# How to run a bash script with su permissions from a none elevated command line

Tags: linux

I've been banging my head at this for some time and can't find an answer.

Disclaimer: I'm a Linux newbie.

So, I received a script to run on a VM at startup and I'm using an Azure template deployment and script extension so I can only run one command, and I run the command like so

```
sudo sh script.sh param1 param2 param3
```

I can change the way I run it as long as it remains one line.

My script is imported to the VM by Azure and run by Azure so I'm not sure of the inner workings but It kept failing because of several permission issues(I did not write the script, was just handed it by the guy who used to run it manually - and I have no idea what the actual issue with the permissions is) and I finally got it to run to completion with using heredoc in this manner:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
sudo su <<"EOF"

var1=$1
var2=$2
var3=$3

rest of script

EOF
```

Now, the script DOES work permission wise but the parameters aren't going through to the su environment - so I found out that I can remove the quotations and then it would work. but THEN I can't create new variables inside the heredoc part.

Can someone come to my aid? :) I have no idea how to solve this apart from re-writing the whole script which will probably take me ages.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you saying that it's failing due to lacking permissions when run with sudo?

Comment: Basically, when I run it via the start up extension with sudo, the script fails. But when I run it manually as root, it works.